# Error al hacer peticion desde http a puerto 443

Tags: apache, virtualhost

lo que pasa es que en el sistema de la pasarela de pagos con la que me he registrado cuando intenta enviarme un POST de confirmación apunta a: http://mi_dominio.com:443/ pero al verificar este me muestra el siguiente error:

Solicitud incorrecta
Su navegador envió una solicitud que este servidor no pudo entender.
Motivo: está hablando HTTP sin formato a un puerto de servidor habilitado para SSL.
En su lugar, utilice el esquema HTTPS para acceder a esta URL, por favor.

en mi servidor tengo el apache así:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mi_dominio.com
Redirect permanent / https://mi_dominio.com:443/
```

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerName mi_dominio.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mi_dominio/public_html

ErrorLog /var/www/mi_dominio/public_html/error.log
SSLENGINE on
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mi_dominio.com.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/mi_dominio.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/mi_dominio.ca-bundle
```

Será que instalé mal el ssl o es la configuracion del apache?

Les agradezco una solución a este problema :)